# Assemble: Managing multiple partials with same file name, in different directories

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, partials, assemble

I'm trying to migrate a large grunt-built project to [Assemble](http://assemble.io/), using [grunt-assemble](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-assemble). I've chosen Assemble for it's handlebars templating engine.

I have two partials named `header.hbs`, placed in different directories like this:
`../partials/foo/header.hbs`
`../partials/bar/header.hbs`

I've tried referencing by `{{> foo/header }}` and `{{> 'foo/header' }}` but both fail with `Warning: The partial foo/header could not be found`.

I can see in the verbose output that two partials with name `header` are created. `{{> header }}` succeeds, but will always return the second file (probably since it was the last one registered).

How can I reference a specific header partial?

Note: I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-assemble/issues/32) on the project's github repo with the same question.

P.S.
I'd be prepared to switch to another grunt tool that'd fit the bill, preferably one that uses handlebars as well.

Comment: I commented on your issue on github. Short answer is it's not possible currently with `grunt-assemble` but we'll consider PRs.